# A question on Liouville's theorem and time-dependence of the Hamiltonian

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

The condition of equilibrium in statistical mechanics is $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=0$ where $\rho$ is the phase space density. By virtue of Liouville's theorem, this is equivalent to the statement $\{\rho,H\}=0$. Mathematically, does this mean that $H$ must also be explicitly time-independent like $\rho$ is?

Comment: Also be careful with explicit vs. total time dependence...

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thanks. So it does not mean that H have to be time-independent.

Comment: Yes, see my explicit answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $H$ is time independent and satisfies $\{\rho, H\}=0$, also $H(t)=f(t)H+ g(t)$ does for every pairs of smooth maps $f,g$. Hence the answer is negative. $H$ can be time dependent.

Comment: Does the derivation of Liouville's theorem hold for a general $H$ with explicit $t$- dependence?

Comment: Yes, in the proof of the Liouville theorem it is not required that $H$ does not explicitly depend on time.