# How do Hamilton's equations deal with non-conservative forces?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, dissipation

I have searched everywhere I know to look but I cannot find out how Hamilton's equations deal with non-conservative forces. In my understanding, Lagrangian mechanics deals with this as follows: the Euler-Lagrange equations no longer have a zero on the right, they have a term $$\Sigma F_q$$ that is the sum of all the non-conservative forces encountered in the direction of the coordinate q.

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}=\Sigma F_q(t)
\end{equation}

The only document I have been able to find about how hamiltonian mechanics deals with non-conservative forces has been: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00692025

It requires you to buy it and I felt like just the plain equations and a little context for an example like a box sliding down a hill against friction would be enough.

Comment: To get the Hamiltonian you extend the Lagrangian to $ L\rightarrow L\left( \overrightarrow{q},\overrightarrow{\dot q}\right) +\overrightarrow{q}\cdot \overrightarrow{f}\left( t\right) $

Answer (score 6):

Lorentz force is an example of non-conservative conservative force that is discussed in pretty much *any* theoretical mechanics textbook. [The Lagrangian is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Lorentz_force_and_analytical_mechanics):
$$L = \frac{m}{2}\dot{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{r}} + q \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r})\cdot\dot{\mathbf{r}} - q\phi(\mathbf{r}),$$
from which the momentum, the Hamiltonian, and the Hamilton equations follow as usual.

Answer (score 6):

1. If a variational formulation of [Lagrange equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) exists (e.g. because of the existence of a generalized velocity-dependent potential $U(q,\dot{q},t)$ for the forces in the problem), then we can in principle derive a [Hamiltonian formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) via a [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) in the standard manner.
2. If no variational Lagrangian formulation exists for Lagrange equations
   $$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^j}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q^j}~=~&Q_j, \cr j~\in~& \{1,\ldots, n\}, \end{align}\tag{L}$$
   but the Lagrangian $L$ is regular/non-degenerate, then we may still derive a Hamiltonian $H$ via a Legendre transformation. However Hamilton's equations get modified
   $$\begin{align} \dot{q}^j~=~\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_j}, & \qquad  \dot{p}_j+\frac{\partial H}{\partial q^j}~=~Q_j, \cr 
   j~\in~&\{1,\ldots, n\}. \end{align}\tag{H}$$
   So there is no conventional Hamiltonian formulation. Nevertheless, several unconventional approaches exist, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147341/2451) related Phys.SE post.