# Routhian for a system with dissipative term

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, dissipation

I was going through the last chapter on "Mechanics" by Lev Landau and Evgeny Lifshitz.
There, in the definition of Routhian, it has not considered the case if a system consists of dissipative term.

So my confusion is while writing Routhian for such systems, which definition of Lagrangian be considered?

Any answer/comments are welcome and thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since the [Routhian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routhian_mechanics) ([Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics)) is a partial (full) [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) of the [Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), respectively, the issues with a Hamiltonian formulation for non-conservative/dissipative systems (as e.g. explained in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/565961/2451)) also applies to a Routhian formulation.
2. Recall that the main advantage of the Routhian formulation is that it Legendre transforms [cyclic position coordinates](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cyclic_coordinates) only in order to make the corresponding momenta constants of motion. However, the latter does not hold for non-conservative/dissipative systems, which basically renders the Routhian construction moot.