# Phase space for a damped harmonic oscillator

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, phase-space, dissipation

Given the equation $x''+2 \beta  x'+ \omega^2 x=0$ for a damped oscillator, I can get to the equation of motion x(t) and deriving it with respect to time: $x'(t)$.
I am asked to plot the phase plane $\{x,x'\}$, considering the 3 cases: $\beta=0$, $\beta  <<  \omega$, $\omega  <<  \beta$.
I have plotted the phase diagram for an undamped harmonic oscillator ($x''+\omega^2 x=0$) which consisted of ellipses but I can´t find a formula linking $x$ and $x'$.$\\$
I have also tried using the Hamiltonian but arrived nowhere.

Comment: Concerning Lagrangian & Hamiltonian formulations, see  e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147341/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: What about the [answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Universal_oscillator_equation) looks problematic to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x(t)$ is a function of time, so is $x'(t)$. You should be able to use time to relate the two.