# Overdamped dynamics and minimization principles

Tags: classical-mechanics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, variational-principle, dissipation

Most physicists are familiar with Hamilton's principle, which allows us to derive the equations of classical mechanics from the principle of stationary action, $$\delta S=0.\tag{1}$$

At the same time, there is Thomson's principle for circuits, which tells us that the current flowing in electric circuit that that which minimized the dissipated power,

$$ P = \sum R I^2. \tag{2}$$

In trying to couple an electrical circuit dynamics to an overdamped dynamics that must satisfy some constraints, I noticed that you can get the correct equations of motion for a conservative force if
you minimize

$$ P = \frac{1}{2} b \dot{x}^2 + \frac{d U}{dx} \dot{x}, \tag{3}$$

over $\dot{x}$, i.e. $$\partial P/\partial \dot{x} = 0,\tag{4}$$
where the first term is the dissipated kinetic energy, and the second term is the time derivative of the
potential $dU/dt$. This principle appears to work fine and can be used to get constrained overdamped dynamics using Lagrange multipliers. The first term looks a little bit like a Rayleigh dissipation function, but I haven't seen the second term in the textbooks I checked.

Have you seen this "principle" before, does it have a name, how is it related to other minimization/stationarity principles in physics?

Comment: As  you mentioned "the correct equations of motion for a conservative force", but the damping forcr is not a conservative force. Not quite understand your meaning.

Comment: @ytlu, what I mean is the equation of motion for overdamped dynamics, i.e., $b\dot{x} = -dU/dx$.

Answer (score 1):

The term $P$ in your expression is an integral of Force by $d\dot{x}$ (by treating $x$ as a constant):

$$
  -\int d\dot{x} F_{total} = - \int d\dot{x} \{-bx - \frac{dU}{dx} \}
$$
Treat $x$ as a constant ans carry out this integral over $d\dot{x}$
$$
  =\frac{1}{2} b\dot{x}^2 + \frac{dU}{dx} \dot{x} = P
$$
Thus, it recovers the force if your partial derives $P$ with respect to $\dot{x}$.

The process here is some what different with the least action principle. The least action principe render the equation of motion $m\ddot{x} = F$ , not only the forces.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I understand that this is not the least action principle. It looks more like a principle of least dissipation. I was wondering if this was known elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Comments to the post (v3):

1. It seems that OP's principle (4) only reproduces the dynamical side $\sum_i{\bf F}_i$ of Newton's 2nd law, not the kinematic side $m{\bf a}$, so it only applies to creeping/overdamped motion.
2. Also OP's principle (4) treats velocity $\dot{x}$ as independent of position $x$. In a conventional [variational action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_principle), they are not independent, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. For a discussion of dissipative forces in a Lagrangian formulation, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147341/2451) Phys.SE post.
4. Goldstein [1] constructs Lagrange equations with [Rayleigh dissipation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_dissipation_function) for $RCL$ circuits.
5. What OP refers to as "Thomson's principle" (2) seems to be the following [2,3]:

   > Given a resistor network with fixed [current sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(circuit_theory)) $I_e$, assign a current $i_e$ to each edge, and impose [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) at each vertex. Then the actual currents minimize the dissipation $\sum_{e}R_e i_e^2$.

   (Refs. [2] & [3] also consider a modified principle where the current sources are replaced by [voltage sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(circuit_theory)).)

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* section 2.5.
2. D. A. Van Baak, [Am. J. Phys. 67 (1999) 36](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.19188).
3. N.R. Sree Harsha, [arXiv:1903.07197](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.07197); eqs. (14)-(17).

Comment: Thank you for the summary! It seems like point 2 is especially strange but it does somehow mirror the Thomson principle: We only care about currents (related to velocity of the charges), but not about the positions of the charges in the circuits.