# Force opposite to velocity vector in Hamiltonian formalism

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, friction, hamiltonian-formalism, dissipation

Consider a system on which a force acts opposite to the velocity direction. We can write its equation of motion such as

$$
m\ddot{\vec{x}} = -F\hat{v}
$$

where the non-conservative force $F$ and the mass $m$ are constant and $\hat{v}$ is the velocity unit vector. Is there a way to express the condition that the force has to be opposite to the velocity vector when we derive the system's Hamiltonian?

Comment: Related: [Lagrangian and Hamiltonian EOM with dissipative force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147341/2451)

Comment: Thank you @Qmechanic! I have already read that question, but my "dissipative force" is not proportional to the velocity magnitude, rather it only depends on the direction. Can I treat my system as the one in the question you referenced?

Comment: Yes, conceptionally, the difference in dissipative force is largely irrelevant. It doesn't change the fact that there is no conventional Hamiltonian formulation. However, check out the unconventional approaches.

Comment: Thank you @Qmechanic