# How to treat viscous force with Lagrange formalism?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, projectile, drag, viscosity

I am trying to figure out how to derive the equations of motion of a particle experiencing a viscous force of magnitude $\mathbf{F}=-c\mathbf{v}$, being $c$ constant and $\mathbf{v}$ the velocity of the mass, using Lagrange formalism.

I'd like to have a:

1. first, a general treatment of the viscous force for the motion of a free particle;
2. then, specialize this treatment of the motion of a constrained particle, moving on a known line. As an example, I'm considering the helix, whose point coordinates are described by the parametric equations:

   $x=R\cos(\theta)$,
   $y=R\sin(\theta)$,
   $z=h(\theta)/2\pi$

   where $R$ and $h$ are constants.

Comment: Dissipative forces like that derived from viscosity cannot be accounted in a "pure" Lagrangian formalism. However, there are some extensions, see the section on the extensions in here: [Wikipedia Lagrangian Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics#Extensions_to_include_non-conservative_forces)

Comment: I'm trying to reopen the question, with some edits. IMHO, a question about treating viscous force (and non-conservative force in general) iwith Lagrange equations is a good question. Many physicists seem to live in a "ideal" world, where everything is conservative, but it's not. Lagrange formalism is very useful and easy to use: treating non-conservative forces is a must to keep using it in the real world models with non ideal terms

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Lagrangian and Hamiltonian EOM with dissipative force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147341/2451)

Comment: @Qmechanic imho, not a duplicate and quite bad answers there

Comment: @Mauricio dissipation function can treat only non-conservative forces that are proportional to the time derivative of the generalized coordinates. It's not general enough in many cases

Comment: @basics you are right, I was just pointing out how different the Lagrangian formalism is with an example of dissipative forces.

Comment: it's open! Yeah!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Lagrangian formalism with non-conservative forces you need to evaluate their *virtual work*

$\delta W = Q_q \, \delta q$,

so that Lagrange equations read

$\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \dot{q}} - \dfrac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial {q}} = Q_q$.

**Free particle.** For the motion of a free particle of mass $m$, experiencing drag $\mathbf{F}^d$, in absence of conservative forces

- the Lagrangian function equals the kinetic energy $\mathscr{L} = T = \dfrac{1}{2} m |\mathbf{\dot{r}}|^2 = \dfrac{1}{2} m \mathbf{\dot{r}} \cdot \mathbf{\dot{r}}$, so that its derivatives appearing in Lagrange equations read

  $\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \mathbf{\dot{r}}} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\left( m \mathbf{\dot{r}} \right) = m \mathbf{\ddot{r}}$$\quad , \qquad$
  $\dfrac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \mathbf{r}} = \mathbf{0}$
- the virtual work reads $\delta W = \mathbf{F}^d \cdot \delta \mathbf{r}$

and the equations of motions read

$ m \mathbf{\ddot{r}} = \mathbf{F}^d$,

as expected.

**Your problem: particle on a helix.** In your problem, the particle is constrained to move on a helix, so that it has only one degree of freedom, namely $\theta(t)$.

- The position of the particle reads
  $\mathbf{r}(t) = R \cos \theta(t) \mathbf{\hat{x}} + R \sin \theta(t) \mathbf{\hat{y}} + \dfrac{h \theta(t)}{2\pi} \mathbf{\hat{z}}$
- The velocity of the particle in a Cartesian basis reads
  $\mathbf{v} = -R\dot\theta \sin \theta \mathbf{\hat{x}} + R\dot\theta \cos \theta \mathbf{\hat{y}} + \dfrac{h \dot\theta}{2 \pi}\mathbf{\hat{z}}$
- The virtual displacement of the particle reads:
  $\delta \mathbf{r} = -R\delta \theta \sin \theta \mathbf{\hat{x}} + R\delta \theta \cos \theta \mathbf{\hat{y}} + \dfrac{h \delta \theta}{2 \pi}\mathbf{\hat{z}}$
- Kinetic energy is

  $K = \dfrac{1}{2} m \left( R^2  + \left(\dfrac{h}{2\pi}\right)^2 \right) \dot\theta^2 $
- Virtual work of drag is

  $\delta W = \mathbf{F}^d \cdot \delta \mathbf{r} = \underbrace{\mathbf{F}^d \cdot \left[ -R \sin \theta \mathbf{\hat{x}} + R \cos \theta \mathbf{\hat{y}} + \dfrac{h }{2 \pi}\mathbf{\hat{z}} \right]}_{Q_{\theta}} \delta \theta$
- Lagrange equation becomes

  $ m \left( R^2  + \left(\dfrac{h}{2\pi}\right)^2 \right) \ddot \theta = \mathbf{F}^d \cdot \left( -R \sin \theta \mathbf{\hat{x}} + R \cos \theta \mathbf{\hat{y}} + \dfrac{h}{2 \pi}\mathbf{\hat{z}} \right)$
- If you model the drag as $\mathbf{F}^d = -c \mathbf{v}$, you can easily find that

  $ m \left( R^2  + \left(\dfrac{h}{2\pi}\right)^2 \right) \ddot \theta = - c \left( R^2 + \left(\dfrac{h}{2\pi}\right)^2 \right) \dot \theta$.

  And **if I made no mistake so far**, last equation becomes $m \ddot \theta + c \dot \theta = 0$.