# Hamilton's equations of motion for damped oscillator

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, friction, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, dissipation

Consider a parallel RLC oscillator. Kirchhoff's equations of motion are
$$
\ddot{\Phi} + \frac{1}{\tau}\dot{\Phi} + \omega_0^2 \Phi = 0
$$
where $\tau = RC$ and $\omega_0 = 1 / \sqrt{LC}$.

1. What is the Lagrangian and associated Euler-Lagrange equations for this system?
2. What is the Hamiltonian and associated Hamilton's equations of motion for this system?

### My attempt

The Lagrangian in the absence of damping is
$$\mathcal L = \frac{1}{2} C \dot{\Phi}^2 - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Phi^2}{L}$$
from which the usual Euler-Lagrange equations give $\ddot \Phi + \omega_0^2 = 0$, the correct equation of motion without damping.

I found a [reference(pdf)](http://www.physics.hmc.edu/%7Esaeta/courses/p111/uploads/Y2013/lec131023-DSHO.pdf) claiming that if the equations of motion are independent of time and the damping is linear, we can write
$$\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \dot q} \right) - \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial q} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial \dot q} = 0$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is Lagrangian without damping and $G$ is the Raleigh dissipation function defined by
$$ G = \frac{1}{2} b \dot{q}^2$$
where $b$ is defined by $F_\text{friction} = -b \dot q$.
In our case, $b = 1/R$ so $G=(1/2) \dot{\Phi}^2/R$.
Let's check that the Euler Lagrange equation works
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \dot q} \right) - \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial q} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial \dot q} &= 0\\
C \ddot{\Phi} + \frac{\Phi}{L} + \frac{\dot{\Phi}}{R} &= 0 \\
\ddot{\Phi} + \omega_0^2 \Phi + \frac{\dot{\Phi}}{\tau} &= 0
\end{align}
which is what we wanted.
It seems we've answered part 1 of the question, i.e. we found a Lagrangian and Euler-Lagrange equation.
But what about the Hamiltonian?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Lagrangian and Hamiltonian EOM with dissipative force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147341/2451)

Answer (score 1):

For real physics applications I'd sugges that you read about the [Caldeira and Leggett model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dissipation). Designed for quantum systems, their model also gives a tractable physical model for classical dissipation.