# How to choose contour of integration prescription Klein- Gordon Propagator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, causality, greens-functions, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

I am going through the complex integral in peskin & Schroeder's intro to QFT (equation 2.54, deriving the Free Klein-Gordon Propagator):
$$\langle0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_p}(e^{-ip(x-y)}-e^{ip(x-y)})$$

I have been able to derive the expression iself by performing the contour integral that is suggested, i.e.:

[image]

However, what I cannot wrap my head around is when P&S talk about choosing either $x^0-y^0 >0$ or $x^0-y^0<0$.
I know that including both poles yields esquation $2.54$, and not including them gives $0$. But I don't really see how the time components come into play in choosing the contour. They end up influencing the sign in the exponents, I fail to see the significance beyond that. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe this answer of mine can help you out: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/742721/. The summary is that, depending on the sign of $x^0 - y^0$, you need to close the integration contour either on the upper or lower half-plane. This ensures that the contribution from the large semi-circle at infinity goes to zero instead of diverging. Such analysis is common when applying the residue theorem to compute improper integrals. See the answer for the full discussion.

Comment: It helped a lot! But I have a question. I am used to use the convention $p^2=(p^0)^2-|p|^2$. By using that, however, I get the opposite result, the Imaginary part in the exponent requires$x^0-y^0<0$. Why am I getting this differing result? Is my convention somehow not valid?

Comment: The resulting $i\epsilon$ prescription does depend on the metric signature. In the mostly minus signature you use one gets a $+i\epsilon$ in the Feynman propagator. In the mostly plus one gets a $-i\epsilon$.