# D'Alembers Principle - further explanation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

In question : [Why is the d'Alembert's Principle formulated in terms of virtual displacements rather than real displacements in time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/289522/why-is-the-dalemberts-principle-formulated-in-terms-of-virtual-displacements-r/289582#289582) there is a response :

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Perhaps a simple example is called for.

*Example.* In 2D consider a point mass $m$ with position ${\bf r}=(x,y)$ that is constrained to move on a frictionless vertical rod, which in turn has pre-determined horizontal position $$x=f(t),\tag{1}$$ where $f$ is a given function of time $t$. In other words, eq. (1) is a holonomic constraint, and there is one [generalized position coordinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) $q\equiv y$, i.e. one degree of freedom. The constraint force ${\bf F}^{(c)}$ is horizontal. The [virtual displacements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_displacement) $\delta q \equiv\delta y$ are by definition vertical with $\delta t=0$, leading to that the constraint force ${\bf F}^{(c)}$ does no virtual work$^1$ 
$$ {\bf F}^{(c)} \cdot \delta {\bf r}~=~0.\tag{2} $$
However if we allow $\delta t\neq 0$, then eq. (2) will no longer hold, and this implies that we can no longer derive [d'Alembert's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'Alembert's_principle) from Newton's 2nd law.

--

$^1$It is tempting to call eq. (2) the [Principle of virtual work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work), but strictly speaking, the *principle of virtual work* is just d'Alembert's principle for a static system. For d'Alembert's principle, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82884/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8453/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

$\boldsymbol {My}$ $\boldsymbol {question}$ is if $\delta t\neq 0$ why will eq. (2) no longer hold?

Comment: „ eq. (1) is a holonomic constraint“ I don’t think so , holonomic constraint is something like this $x^2+y^2=L^2$ for example

Comment: So in your example you don’t have constraint force at all

Comment: @Eli - the response I quoted has a constraint force, so are you suggesting that the response I quoted is incorrect ? In any case what is the exact difference between the virtual time =0 and an actual displacement in time behaviour in this case ?

Comment: equation (2) is a dot product between the constraint force and the virtuelle displacement which is not a function of time

Comment: @Eli If (2) doesn't hold, what would the revised equation be for a differential increase in time ?

Comment: Hi @Little Cheese. I updated the original answer. Does it still need further explanation?

Comment: @Qmechanic Not sure. Eli says your eq (1) is not holonomic, but your words say it is ? I have read most of the 250 or so answers on D'Alemberts principle but still don't get it ! It looks like all thats being done is to absorb the constraints into the generalised coordinates - but this is confused by the virtual / normal differential movements (or at least it has confused me!).

Comment: @Little Cheese: It is holonomic by definition. I updated the [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/289582/2451). How about now?

Comment: @Qmechanic. Apologies, I still don't understand why "if we allow δt≠0, then eq. (2) will no longer hold" (apart from the obvious - its a change from the definition). Is there an easy example to explain what goes wrong? Goldstein says enigmatically, but with no explanation : "No variation in time ...since only then is the virtual displacement perpendicular to the force of constraint if the constraint itself is changing in time".

Comment: @Little Cheese: I updated the [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/289582/2451). How about now?

Comment: @Qmechanic. Very neat & simple demonstration of what goes wrong, thanks.

Comment: @Little Cheese: Do you mind if I close your post as a duplicate?

Comment: @Qmechanic - yup go ahead and mark it as a duplicate. (A minor point in (6) how does ∂r/∂q become just ey - it looks like there should be another multiplier present, but it doesn't affect the answer?)

Comment: @Little Cheese: I updated the [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/289582/2451).