# Using normal displacement instead of virtual displacement

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, displacement

I know that there are many posts about virtual displacement, but I want to answer the question if of: is virtual displacement is always needed to get the same results? I am going through a PDF by Subhankar Ray & J. Shamanna  on virtual work [Here](https://archive.org/details/arxiv-physics0410123/page/n5/mode/2up). So the main idea is how far we can get using allowed displacement opposed to virtual displacement:

**If the constraints are not time dependent, then we have the similar property**

\begin{equation}\tag{a}
\sum^N_{k=1}(m_k\textbf{a}_k - \textbf{F}_k)\cdot d\textbf{r}_k = 0
\end{equation}
**2.Using Generalized Coordinates**

We then read on and we note that because of the constraints, not all the $d\textbf{r}_k$ are independent of eachother and so we then want to change it to independent parameters to remove this issue.

So to change the parameters we use
\begin{equation}
d\textbf{r}_k = \sum^N_{k=1}\frac{\partial \textbf{r}_k}{\partial q_j}dq_j +\frac{\partial\textbf{r}_k}{\partial t}dt
\end{equation}
opposed to
\begin{equation}\tag{23}
\delta\textbf{r}_k = \sum^N_{k=1}\frac{\partial \textbf{r}_k}{\partial q_j}\delta q_j
\end{equation}

thus we will get for $({a})$,

\begin{equation}\tag{b}
\sum^N_{k=1}(m_k\textbf{a}_k - \textbf{F}_k)\cdot \left(\sum^N_{k=1}\frac{\partial \textbf{r}_k}{\partial q_j}dq_j +\frac{\partial\textbf{r}_k}{\partial t}dt\right) = 0
\end{equation}

**My Question**

From above, $(b)$, I am having a hard time picturing this. I feel like the "$\frac{\partial\textbf{r}_k}{\partial t}dt$" part may cause issues(just like when the constraint equation was time dependent and $d\textbf{r}_k$ was no longer tangential to the constraint equation)-or am I worrying about nothing. I would be grateful for any insight you can offer.

**Edit**
Like I feel like that
\begin{equation}\tag{b}
\sum^N_{k=1}(m_k\textbf{a}_k - \textbf{F}_k)\cdot \left(\sum^N_{k=1}\frac{\partial \textbf{r}_k}{\partial q_j}dq_j \right) = 0
\end{equation}

should hold as we are moving the object *with the idea that time is frozen*.

Is there any sense to this line of reasoning?

Comment: Permalink: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0410123

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81742/2451 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/520835/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic, thank you for your reply. I read over the 2 posts and I think there is one main difference between my post and those, that is the constraints I am looking at are those that are not time depenedent, but the ones in the post include time dependency. I believe that we can use $d\textbf{r}$ instead of $\delta \textbf{r}$ if the constraints are not time depenedent- if what I say is correct, we may have an issue at arriving at the lagrange equation as we can't remove the $+ \frac{\partial\textbf{r}}{\partial t}dt$