# Friction as a Non-conservative force

Tags: forces, friction, work, conservative-field

Intuitively, one can find friction to be a [non-conservative force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force).  How can one prove that it is non-conservative?

Comment: Just check that the usual friction terms do not fulfill the definition of a [conservative force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force).

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20929/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

A conservative force must satisfy the property that the total work done must be independent of the path traveled.  In physics, work is defined as the force along a given path times the distance of this path so that, simply:

$$
\text{work} = \sum_\text{paths} F\cdot l_\text{path} = \sum_\text{paths} \text{force along path}\times \text{path distance}
$$

Since force of friction is along the direction one is traveling, taking a different path will accumulate work which is given by

$$
\text{work}_\text{friction} = \sum_\text{paths} F_\text{friction}\cdot l_\text{path} = F_\text{friction}\times\text{length of total path}
$$

Finally, since the work done by the friction depends on the path one takes, it is not considered a conservative force.

On a less rigorous note, any force which converts some form of kinetic energy or potential energy into heat will not satisfy the property of a conservative force.

Answer (score -2):

1.It does not follow law of conservation of mass

2.work done by this force in a loop is equal to zero

3.it depends on path followed by the object (body)