# Does work done by/against friction depend on path length or displacement?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work, friction, distance, displacement

On an equipotential surface, does the work done in moving/sliding a block of mass depend only on the initial and final position or the circuitous path (notwithstanding work done by or against friction and neglecting sign-convention)?

Comment: Have you tried computing the work done? This should directly answer your question if you try 1.5 time around vs 0.5 times.

Comment: I believe [this answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/193581/145491) your question about the path dependence of friction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Friction as a Non-conservative force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193580/)