# Derive Generalized forces using Hamilton's principle

Tags: forces, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, variational-principle

When you derive the Euler-Lagrange equation using D'Alembert's principle, you find that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_j}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_j}=Q_j$$ where $$Q_j=\vec{F}·\frac{d\vec{r}}{dq_j}$$ (Goldstein, p. 23-24). But if you use Hamilton's principle and some calculus of variations (Goldstein, p. 44 ff.), you only obtain the formula with $Q_j=0$. Is it possible to put the generalized forces into the Euler-Lagrange equation without deriving it from D'Alembert's principle? I tried to use some kind of lagrange multiplier to insert additional forces, but was not able to derive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if all the generalized forces have generalized potentials. Which need not be the case, in particular for dissipative systems, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20929/2451) Phys.SE post. So *No,* that's in general not possible. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451) related Phys.SE post.