# External force dependent on velocity on a Lagrangian

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, velocity

The question I have is, what conditions must satisfy an external force dependent on velocity so it can be a part of the lagrangian and Euler-Lagrange equations are still true.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Velocity-Dependent Potential and Helmholtz Identities](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489613/2451)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Velocity-Dependent Potential and Helmholtz Identities](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489613/)

Answer (score 0):

The (non-relativistic) Lagrangian force is $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}$, with variables $q$ and $\dot{q}$ considered independent, thus term of the form $\delta L = q F(\dot{q})$ is interpreted as velocity dependent force $ F(\dot{q})$ on coordinate $q$. Notice that as long as $F$ doesn't explicitly depends on coordinate  $q$ (but may be fependent on others) - $F$ can be function of velocities of all the coordines. For example $F = F(|\dot{\vec{q}}|) = -\gamma \sqrt{\dot{q_1}^2+\dot{q_2}^2+\dot{q_3}^2}$