# Why can't $U=b\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{r}$ be considered a potential for the drag force ${\bf F}=-b {\bf v}$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, friction, potential-energy, drag

Consider the function $U(\mathbf{r},\dot{\mathbf{r}})=b\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{v}=bx\dot{x}+by\dot{y}+bz\dot{z}$, where $b$ is the drag coefficient. Why can't this be considered as a potential energy for the drag force? It can easily seen that $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=b\dot{x}$$, for the $x$ coordinate and similarly for the $y$ and $z$ coordinates. Collecting in vector form, and using the well-known relation $\mathbf{F}=-\nabla U$, one gets $$\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{drag}}=-\nabla U=-b\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{r}}{\mathrm{d} t}.$$
But according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force), a force is conservative if it can be written as the negative gradient of a potential energy, so this would make drag conservative, and it says nothing about velocity dependence, so that doesn't matter, but it is usually regarded as a non-conservative force. Then, why can't drag be regarded as a conservative force?

Comment: Wikipedia article that you mention states that "A conservative force is dependent only on the position of the object."

Answer (score 8):

1. A velocity-dependent potential $U=U({\bf r},{\bf v},t)$ of a force ${\bf F}$ satisfies by definition 
   $${\bf F}~=~\color{red}{\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial U}{\partial {\bf v}}} - \frac{\partial U}{\partial {\bf r}} \tag{1}$$
   rather than
   $${\bf F}~=~ - \frac{\partial U}{\partial {\bf r}},\qquad\qquad (\leftarrow\text{Wrong!} ) \tag{2}$$
   cf. Ref. 1. The idea being that in order for a notion of potential $U$ to be useful, it should yield an [action formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action). The extra red term in eq. (1) can be viewed as a consequence of [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation).
2. A proof that the drag force 
   $${\bf F}~=~-b {\bf v}  \tag{3}$$
   does *not* have a velocity-dependent potential $U=U({\bf r},{\bf v},t)$ is given in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20929/2451) Phys.SE post.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* Chapter 1.

Comment: I can't comment so I'll write it here. Qmechanic your first equation is i believe an expression for generalised force rather than force.

Comment: @Yasir Sadiq: I agree.