# How do I include friction due to normal force in Lagrange Equations?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, friction, dissipation, contact-mechanics

I am going through the Goldstein book on classical mechanics and the after he derived the Lagrange equations he used Rayleigh dissipation function to include friction as a generalized force. In school we wrote friction as a function of the normal force: $$F_f = \mu N,$$

but I thought that the normal force was considered a constraint force, so is there any way to include the friction equation with the normal force as a generalized force in stead of the ${\bf F}_f = -k{\bf v}$ equation?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Lagrangian and Hamiltonian EOM with dissipative force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147341/2451) and links therein.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lagrangian and Hamiltonian EOM with dissipative force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147341/)

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question because I am still unclear of how the frictional force due to normal force is related.

Comment: I think [this article](https://profoundphysics.com/friction-in-lagrangian-mechanics/) should answer your question in a pretty simply way. One of the examples given there is about friction from a normal force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to insert friction forces in the Lagrangian  for a crucial reason: friction forces of the type you consider have absolute value proportional to the normal component of the  reactive force due to  the constraint. This force does **not** appear in the Euler-Lagrange formalism just because it has been constructed to that goal. The E-L formalism only deals with (components of) forces and accelerations **tangent** to the constraints. In other words,  there is no way to translate  the relation $|F|= \mu |N|$ in the E-L formalism.
The case of friction  forces proportional to the velocity can be treated in the  E-L formulation as pointed out in the other answer by ZeroTheHero.

Answer (score 2):

how to consider friction force and calculate the equations of motion with E.L method.

the  Euler- Lagrange equation are:

$$\begin{align*}
   &L  =T-U\\
   &\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\vec{q}}}\right)-
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{q}}=\left(\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{q}}\right)^T\vec{f}_a+
  \left(\frac{\partial \vec{g}_h}{\partial \vec{q}}\right)^T\vec{\lambda}_h
 \end{align*}\tag 1$$

- $T$ kinetic energy
- $U$ potential  energy
- $\vec{q}$ generalized coordinates
- $\vec{r}$ position vector
- $\vec{f}_a$ external forces
- $\vec{g}_h$ holonomic constrains
- $\vec{\lambda}_h$ holonomic constrain forces

**I) the friction force is considered as external force.**

**II) the friction  normal force is calculate with holonomic constraint equation.**

**Example:**

[image]

a mass point slides on a circle path, with a friction between the mass and the path.

beginning with the position vector of the mass:

$$\vec{r}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \rho\, \left( 1-\cos \left( {\frac {s}{\rho}
} \right)  \right) \\ \rho\,\sin \left( {\frac {s}{
\rho}} \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$ 
where $\rho$ is the circle radius and s the arc length.

the friction force $F\mu$ act towards the path  tangent $\vec{t}$ with the sign apposite to the tangent velocity $v_t$

with :

$$\vec{t}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial s}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \sin \left( {\frac {s}{\rho}} \right) 
\\\cos \left( {\frac {s}{\rho}} \right) 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

thus:

$$F\mu=\mu\,|N|\,\text{sign}(-v_t)$$
where $v_t=\vec{v}^T\,\vec{t}\quad,\vec{v}=\vec{\dot{r}}$

so the external force is:

$$\vec{f}_a=F\mu\,\vec{t}$$

to obtain the normal force N , we create  a gap $q_N$ toward the normal direction $\vec{n}$, thus we have now two generalized coordinates $\vec{q}=[s,q_N]^T$

the mass position vector is now:

$$\vec{r}\mapsto \vec{r}+q_N\vec{n}$$

with:

$$n=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -\cos \left( {\frac {s}{\rho}} \right) 
\\ \sin \left( {\frac {s}{\rho}} \right) 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

you can now obtain the kinetic energy and potential energy:

$$T=\frac{m}{2}\vec{\dot{r}}^T\vec{\dot{r}}$$
$$U=m\,g\,r_y$$

the holonomic constrain equation  is:

$$g_h=q_N=0\quad 
 \Rightarrow\quad \dot{q}_N=0\quad,\ddot{q}_N=0$$

with equation (1) ,you can calculate the equation of motion and the normal force . you have two equations for two unknowns $ \ddot{s}\,,N=\lambda_h$

**results:**

with equation (1) you get:

$$m\,\ddot{s}+m\,g\,\cos\left(\frac{s}{\rho}\right)-F\mu=0\tag 2$$

and

$$m\,\ddot{q}_N+\frac{m\,\dot{s}^2}{\rho}+
m\,g\,\sin\left(\frac{s}{\rho}\right)-N=0\tag 3$$

with $\ddot{q}_N=0$

$ \Rightarrow$

$$N=m\,g\,\sin\left(\frac{s}{\rho}\right)-\frac{m\,\dot{s}^2}{\rho}$$

$$\ddot{s}-\frac{F\mu}{m}+g\,\cos\left(\frac{s}{\rho}\right)=0$$

**Simulation**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The constraint provided by the normal force is one that will keep the particle on the surface of an object.  The friction force, on the other hand, is NOT a constraint even if the normal force is.  Because it is not obtained from a potential, it *must* be included by hand as a generalized force.

Nevertheless, it is possible to reproduce the correct equations of motion with dissipation of the form $F=- \kappa \dot{x}$ by considering the time-dependent Lagrangian
$$
L= e^{\alpha t}\left(\frac{m}{2} \dot{x}^2- \frac{k}{2}x^2\right)
$$
You can then derive that, since 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}=\frac{d}{dt}
me^{\alpha t}\dot{x}= me^{\alpha t}(\alpha \dot{x} +\ddot{x}) 
$$
the resulting equation of motion accounts for dissipation for a suitable choice of $\alpha$.

As $L$ is explicitly time-dependent, the Hamiltonian is not conserved (not unexpectedly).

Comment: Ok, from what I understand in your answer it is only possible to write the Lagrangian for the frictional case using the exponential term to decay the Lagrangian over time and the dissipation form of friction to reach the equations of motion, but not using the normal force friction equation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Concerning [kinetic friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction) $$F_f~\equiv~|{\bf F}_f|~=~\mu |{\bf F}_n|,\tag{1}$$ let us for simplicity assume that the surfaces stay in contact at all time, and the contact surface is a plane (possibly inclined), i.e that $F_f$ is a constant.

   - Then the friction force is
     $$ {\bf F}_f~=~-F_f\frac{\bf v}{|{\bf v}|}.\tag{2}$$
   - The corresponding [Rayleigh dissipation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_dissipation_function) is
     $$ {\cal F}~=~ F_f |{\bf v}|, \qquad {\bf F}_f ~=~-\frac{\partial {\cal F}}{\partial{\bf v}}.\tag{3}$$
     Recall that Lagrange equations can readily be modified to accommodate the 
     Rayleigh dissipation function, cf. e.g. eq. (1.70) in Goldstein or [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451) Phys.SE post.
   - On the other hand, one may show that there does *not* exist a velocity-dependent potential $U$ for the friction force (2), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20929/2451) Phys.SE post, not even in 1D.
2. Lagrangian formulations of [linear friction/drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)) (which OP also mentions) is discussed in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147341/2451) related Phys.SE post.

References:

1. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Section 1.5 eq. (1.70).