# Monogenic forces vs generalized forces

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy

Wikipedia article under generalized forces says

[image]

Also we know that the generalized forces are defined as

[image]

How can I derive the first equation from the second for a monogenic system?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_system#cite_ref-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Concerning OP's question (v3), it follows by definition without the use of eq. (2).

1. The first equation is the very definition of a [monogenic force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_system), i.e. that the force has a generalized (possibly velocity-dependent) potential.
2. The second equation is the definition of a [generalized force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_forces).

Eq. (1) is a special case of eq. (2), but *not* vice-versa.

*Example:* A friction force is a generalized force that is *not* monogenic, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20929/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: So the generalized force for a  monogenic system which you call as monogenic  force is just defined as having two terms and therefore can't be derived from the more general definition of the generalised force involving a summation?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: In the special case then is this correct $Q_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbf{F}_{i} \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_{i}}{\partial q_{j}}$=$-\frac{\partial \mathcal{V}}{\partial q_{i}}+\frac{d}{d t}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{V}}{\partial \dot{q}_{i}}\right)$ ?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: And we can't prove explicitly that the summation on the LHS equals the RHS for a monogenic case?